# dictionary-style header problem with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying the `fancyhdf.pdf` page 11 example. But I find I am getting wrong headers like `Foo--Foo` on the first page of the `Foo` entry, but correctly `Foo` on subsequent pages. The reason seems to be that the `equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}` command is failing because `\leftmark` is lower case, and `\rightmark` is upper case. I cannot find any way to fix this. Any suggestions? My code is:

```
\renewcommand{\parishmarks}{% as in fancyhdr.pdf page 11, but with \nouppercase added
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}{\rightmark}{\nouppercase\rightmark--\leftmark}}

\fancyhead[L]{\chaptermark}\fancyhead[R]{\parishmarks}
```

See [How can I achieve dictionary headers for two page spreads in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/how-can-i-achieve-dictionary-headers-for-two-page-spreads-in-latex)

---

Here is a complete example.  Without the \renewcommand, the first page has "-AAA" where it should have "AAA".

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,ifthen}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{} % turn off section marks

% create a command to create marks and collapse them if they are identical...
\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\rightmark} % if equal
{`\rightmark'--`\leftmark'}} % if not equal

\renewcommand{\mymarks}{% fix the case where \rightmark is an empty string \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\rightmark} % if equal
{\ifthenelse{\equal{}{\rightmark}}{\leftmark}{\rightmark--\leftmark}}} % if not equal

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\mymarks}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}\markboth{AAA}{AAA} % this goes wrong without the fix

\noindent This is the first section.

\clearpage\markboth{CCC}{BBB}

\noindent This is a new page, not a new section.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem that the community can play with? It'll make things easier for us and you, speeding up a response time.

Comment: If you're in a hurry, there's a complete example here: [Indexing an interval of words on top of every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26122)

Comment: Thanks - but making a minimal example would be hard, as it's a 500 page book.   I looked at the complete example, but it's the same as what I already have.  I will have to debug my code some more...

Comment: I have a minimal example where it fails.   If a new section starts at the top of a page, then the method given at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26122/indexing-an-interval-of-words-on-top-of-every-page goes wrong. For example, if this is added:\section{Adjourn section}
\begin{itemize}
\ditem[adjourn] \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}  I would be grateful for a suggested fix.

Comment: Here is a complete example.  Without the \renewcommand, the first page has "-AAA" where it should have "AAA".