# Classical encyclopedia or dictionary index reference style

Tags: header-footer, indexing

In classical encyclopedias and dictionaries you can often find a reference to the first entry (and sometimes the last) entry of that page.
E.g., in the header of the page (alpha - bravo) means that alpha is the first index entry on the page and bravo is the last one.
I would like to create such a style for my index by placing this information in either the header or the footer. Currently, I use the standard LaTeX indexing mechanism (with `makeindex` and a style file in combination with the `memoir` class) to generate the index, however I could not find an easy way to implement this. Does anyone know which packages or custom code support this?

Comment: Related and/or possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/how-can-i-achieve-dictionary-headers-for-two-page-spreads-in-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30392/how-could-one-setup-a-layout-for-a-dictionary-if-possible

Comment: indeed this topic can be closed (duplicate)